# Why Free Pascal automatically pass record data to xmm registers?

Tags: assembly, sse, inline-assembly, simd, freepascal

I have data type called `TVector` as follows:

```
type
   TVector = record
       x,y,z,w : single;
   end;
```

and I have variables named `v1` and `v2` which contain following data:

```
v1.x:=1;
v1.y:=2;
v1.z:=3;
v1.w:=4;

v2.x:=5;
v2.y:=6;
v2.z:=7;
v2.w:=8;
```

Both variables are passed to method as follows:

```
function TSSEVectorOperation.add(const vect1: TVector; const vect2: TVector): TVector; assembler;
asm
   ...
   addps xmm1, xmm2
   movaps xmm0, xmm1
   ...
end;
```

When I debug and step into `add()` method using Lazarus IDE (in Ubuntu), I learned that initially `xmm0` - `xmm3` registers contain values from `v1` and `v2` in following order

```
xmm0 = {1,2,0,0}
xmm1 = {3,4,0,0}
xmm2 = {5,6,0,0}
xmm3 = {7,8,0,0}
```

My question is why Free Pascal does it like that? Why not in the order as follows?

```
xmm0 = {1,2,3,4}
xmm1 = {5,6,7,8}
```

or why not let me manually assign value to xmm registers? Something like:

```
movaps xmm0, vect1
movaps xmm1, vect2
```

Comment: It's the platform calling convention that determines this.

Comment: It makes sense. Default calling convention is `register` which try to pass data to register as much as possible.

Comment: No. On x64 the platform defines the calling convention and register, stdcall, cdecl etc. are all ignored.

Comment: Do you mean that if I run this app on different machine, it may use different calling mechanism?

Comment: Yes. If you compile for Windows, or for a 32 bit target then the calling convention differs.

Comment: The reason is that with x86-64 on Linux structures can be passed by value in the XMM registers. The 64-bit Linux ABI calling convention can be found [here](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) . One peculiarity in the rules for passing structures is that no more than 64-bits of data can be passed in an XMM register. 2 floats is 8 bytes or 64-bits. The first two will passed in XMM0 and the second two in XMM1.

Comment: Of course XMM2 and XMM3 will contain the second vector structure.

Comment: Thanks. That explains everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Michael Petch in comment and after digging System V ABI document. FreePascal does follow x86-64 ABI calling convention (my ubuntu is 14.04 LTS 64-bit) which will pass floating-point parameters to `xmm` registers in the order as I mentioned in my question.

So in order to combine low quadword of `xmm0` and `xmm1` registers into `xmm0` register, I need to use `movlhps` instruction

```
 movlhps xmm0, xmm1
```

Same thing goes with `xmm2` and `xmm3` registers.

Function that returns floating-point value need to store its result in `xmm0`  register. If result is more than 64-bit floating-point then remaining 64-bit goes to `xmm1` register. So for my case, it should be

```
 xmm0 = {result.x, result.y, (not used), (not used)}
 xmm1 = {result.z, result.w, (not used), (not used)}
```